# Using for...in and instanceof for parsing objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'm attempting to loop through an object and use different functions on each different sub-object based on it's type. **instanceof** seemed to be the only way to identify non-built in types, so I attempted to use it with **for...in**; however, I'm not getting the expected output.

Here is a sample fiddle to illustrate my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/zv230dvL/2/

```
function testObject(){}
function testContainer(objects){
  this.zero = objects[0];
  this.one = objects[1];
  this.two = objects[2];
}
var singleObject = new testObject();
var container = new testContainer(
  [new testObject(),
   new testObject(),
   new testObject()]
);
...
//Testing if a single object functions as expected
out(singleObject instanceof testObject);
//Testing if directly referencing an object
//in a container functions as expected
out(container.zero instanceof testObject);
//iterating through a container object...
for(i in container){
 out(i instanceof testObject);   
}
```

The output is

```
true
true
false
false
false
```

First, what would be the appropriate method to do something like this?

Second, why does the variable in the **for...in** loop behave in this manner?

no jQuery please.

Comment: `console.log(i);` --- **ALWAYS** check what actually is in variables, not just make assumptions.

Comment: I need to stop coding sleep deprived. I was assuming that for...in functioned like C++ style iterator. container[i] seems to function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you iterate an Object with `for..in`, the loop variable will have the key, *in string type*. So, you should be checking like this

```
for (i in container) {
    out(container[i] instanceof testObject);
}
```

Now, you are using the object corresponding to the key `i` in `container`. With this change, all the items will evaluate to `true`.

**Note:** `for..in` is supposed to give all the inherited properties as well. So, the normal looping pattern when you use `for..in` with an Object is

```
for (i in container) {
    if (container.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        out(container[i] instanceof testObject);
    }
}
```

This will make sure that, only the properties which are directly defined in the object are checked.